# Convert the Specific string to date and check it is greater than current date

Tags: java, datetime

I have a `string s="2020-04-07T13:43:49-05:00"`

i have to check if its greater than current date and i tried using instant date

```
Instant timestamp = Instant.parse(string);
```

But did not work and i tried with `LocalDate`

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(string, format);
```

this is also not working, how to parse it and check

Comment: You can use SimpleDateFormat for parsing string to required date format.

Comment: I tried can you try with above example..it didn;t work

Comment: @SumitDesai That’s a very bad idea.  `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Use the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse(String)` and avoid the need for an explicit formatter completely.

Answer (score 2):

You should parse it into [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) since date string has an offset

> A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00.

```
String s="2020-04-07T13:43:49-05:00";

OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(s);
```

and then check weather it is greater than or not using [isBefore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-) or [isAfter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-) by converting into [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

```
LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(dateTime.toLocalDateTime())
```

You can also compare `OffsetDateTime` directly using `isBefore` and `isAfter`

```
OffsetDateTime.now().isBefore(dateTime)
```

Comment: Comparing to `LocalDateTIme` is incorrect and can give incorrect results if the two times are less than about 26 hours apart. The comparison to `OffsetDateTime.now()` is correct and the one to go with.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me using Java (`jshell`) 13:

```
jshell> import java.time.Instant

jshell> Instant.parse("2020-04-07T13:43:49-05:00")
$2 ==> 2020-04-07T18:43:49Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat for this. Take your string and format it to the date and then check for it.

```
Date date= new Date();
String targetDate="2020-04-07 13:43:49";
Date date2= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(targetDate);
```

Now you can just check the two date by

```
if(date.getTime()>date2.getTime())
```

If you want to do it opposite way you can do that too.

```
Date date= new Date();
String currentDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date)
```

now just check the two strings with if condition.

Comment: No, no, please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.